# How can I add features to a GRID raster dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, editing, tin, esri-grid-format

I am using a high resolution GRID, but unfortunatelly have realized I have portions of no data within it. As a solution I have decided to create and add the elevations myself for some of the areas. In order to do this I have created a separate feature class containing the additional features with coresponding elevations.

Is there a way I can incorporate the feature class into the GRID or do I have to convert it into a TIN?

( i know I can then use the add feature to tin TOOL). dUEto the high resolution, TIN will not work out, process keeps on giving me errors. (I am using ArcMap 10.1)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to convert your feature class to a GRID using the elevation attribute, Feature to Raster in Toolbox. Cell size and projection should be the same as the GRID you want it to go into. Then add the grids together in Raster Calculator.